# Create separate Unity project for headless server

Tags: networking, server, unity-game-engine

I want to create a headless server that handles my multiplayer game. This will be more a proof-of-concept project, but basically I just want to have multiple players (lets say 3) to move a box around. So every player can move the box at the same time (imagine a football being moved around by multiple players).

Now I'm wondering how I should structure my code. I was thinking to have a separate project for the server, which I can run headless on a linux server, and another project for the game itself. All the server does is pass messages around where the box currently is and who moved it.

I'm new to Unity, so not sure if this is wise. Or should I put the server as a separate scene in the same project? Or a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Note, Unity mmp "MLAPI" in the 2020s:

Recently Unity have (yet again) completely changed their approach to realtime multiplayer, it's the "MLAPI" system now for a few years until they totally change it again.

https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com

This very old article deals only with the abstract concept of the "three ways" to have server/clients, so, here's the old article:

You've hit on a great question.

## Here are the three possibilities:

(A) Some prefer to have **both sides** in the **one script**. (IE, there is only the one project. And indeed each *script* literally "does both things".)

(B) Some prefer to have **two scripts**, but in the **one project**.  So the app launches, and then, the app then *decides* whether it is a server or client.

(C) Some prefer to have **two utterly separate projects**.  So, one project is the client and one is the server.

So you have to decide between the three approaches.

Regarding "A":

1. Unfortunately most of the ancient code samples on the web, from the the early days of Unity, are of form "A". Some of these samples are extremely bad.
2. I find approach "A" confusing and pointless. I cannot see *any* purpose in combining the two concepts in to one.

Regarding "B":

1. This is maybe the way to go for medium-size projects.  However, the app has to fundamentally know how to "split itself" in to two distinct apps.
2. B is easier than C for the people *deploying* the app. They just launch the app. The app figures out how to behave. But, B is harder for the developers.

Regarding "C":

1. If the system is something to do with security or transactions, you'll want C. Everything is KISS and there is less chance of confusion. If the two parts of the system are naturally more different, C makes sense.
2. If the project is very large C is easier since the project is more broken-up. It will make you more naturally formalize the communications protocol between the two, etc etc.

C is "always correct".  B can be useful for "deployment convenience".  And sure, if you're just making a "hello world" test, you can do "A", but it is very confusing.

---

To get a further opinion on this difficult question, one would have to clearly present the deployment case; i.e. is it an app store game, is it a one-off kiosk installation, factory-wide software, or whatever the case may be.  Cheers

Comment: @Jow Blow Thanks for lot for the summary! It's exactly what I was experiencing. I got so confused when I found that basically all resources put both server/host and client in one project. Maybe because most Unity devs are actually game designer and less programmers? Either way. I have, I think, a pretty basic setup. A game object that can be transformed by all connected clients (I will think about permissions later, but right now I just assume that clients will wait for the other to finish their actions before doing their own). Maybe data files might be send between clients.

Comment: I just feel it's super confusing to write a server in a separate project, cause everything is so highly entangled in all documentations, tutorials and examples.

Comment: I must tell you clearly: ***most example code you see for Unity laying around, is total - absolute - complete - crap***.  This is ***absolutely true*** in many aspects of Unity.  I will tell you exactly and specifically why this is: Unity is a field with ***a handful of professional engineers, and millions of hobbyists who literally know nothing about programming***.  For this reason, bizarre code examples crop up that are ***a complete pile of crap*** and the examples and techniques get repeated everywhere. That's the specific reason for the laughable Unity code samples you see around.

Comment: Thanks for the laugh! I feel completely the same. Unfortunately doesn't make it any easier for me.

Comment: @Phytochrome did you finally managed to separate server and client code?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Fattie's answer, I did encounter an issue by going with the 3rd option. That is, creating seperate projects for server and client.

Mainly, **RPC calls** probably **won't work**, since the rpc method signature will be different in a new project because of a different assembly name (as noted in the  [compatibility documentation](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/advanced-topics/message-system/rpc-compatibility)).

The workaround is to copy your current project to keep all the assembly names intact and rework your project to fit your needs.